# How to get information from instagram with cheerio and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cheerio

I am trying to get the username of the profile on the url of that users page. Just to figure out the basic of getting Instagram data

The code below is what I have tried to do and miserably failed(also I am a beginner sorry for bad code)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request-promise');
const path = require('path');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
const app = express()

var followers = [];

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.instagram.com/unrivaledhype/'
  }, function(err, response, body, callback) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);

    $ = cheerio.load(url);

    var post = $("*");
    var follwerCount = post.find('h1').text();
    console.log(follwerCount);
    followers.push({follwerCount: follwerCount})
  });

  res.send(JSON.stringify(followers, null, 4));
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

It just displays follwerCount:"" but(even though I named it misspelled followerCount I went for the username) although if someone can show me how to get the follower count that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Instagram pages are rendered on the client side, so it is **not possible** to get information like the number of followers through this way.

A solution to this problem would be to use [puppeteer](https://youtu.be/dXjKh66BR2U).
With puppeteer you can start a headless version of chrome, which also interprets javascript, so that Instagram pages get rendered completely.

---

**Example code:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

class InstagramClient {
  async start() {
    this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true //When set to true, a new browser window will ge opened
    })
  }

  async stop() {
    await this.browser.close()
  }

  async getFollowers(username) {
    if (!this.browser) throw new Error('Browser not started')

    const page = await this.browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(`https://instagram.com/${username}/`)

    const pageExists = await page.evaluate(_ => {
      return document.querySelector('.error-container') === null
    })
    if (!pageExists) {
      throw new Error(`Page of ${username} doesn't exist`)
    }

    //Wait until the page got completly renderer
    await page.waitForSelector('h1')

    const followers = await page.evaluate(username => {
      //This code will get executed on the instagram page

      //Get the number of followers
      const followers = document.querySelector(`a[href="/accounts/login/?next=%2F${username}%2Ffollowers%2F&source=followed_by_list"]`).querySelector('span').innerText
      //Return the number of followers back to the node process
      return followers
    }, username)

    page.close()

    return followers
  }
}

module.exports = InstagramClient
```

---

```
const InstagramClient = require('./utils/instagram-client')

async function start() {
  const client = new InstagramClient()
  await client.start()

  console.log('@instagram:', await client.getFollowers('instagram'))
  console.log('@unrivaledhype:', await client.getFollowers('unrivaledhype'))
  console.log('@teslamotors:', await client.getFollowers('teslamotors'))

  await client.stop()
}

start()
```

Output:

```
@instagram: 309m
@unrivaledhype: 3,230
@teslamotors: 6m
```

If you want a more detailed explanation, check out this video: 
[A Guide to Web Scraping with NodeJS](https://youtu.be/dXjKh66BR2U)

---

**Express example:**

```
const express = require('express')
const InstagramClient = require('./utils/instagram-client')

const app = express()
const client = new InstagramClient()

app.get('/:instagramName/followers', async (request, response) => {
  const instagramName = request.params.instagramName
  try {
    const followers = await client.getFollowers(instagramName)
    response.json({
      success: true,
      followers: followers
    })
  } catch (e) {
    response.json({
      success: false,
      error: e.toString()
    })
    return
  }
})

async function start() {
  await client.start()
  app.listen(3000, _ => console.log('Server is listening on port 3000'))
}

start()
```

Comment: thanks but there is no way to put this up on a browser or localhost?

Comment: Added an express example

Comment: Thank you so much. But as I told you I am a complete beginner at express and node.js in general so in order for the program to actually work what would I have to do. Like can you show me what to replace to get the Tesla followers. Very sorry to keep bothering you but this would be very helpful.

Comment: Hey can u please help me with this? You have helped me a lot but even though I have scrolled through the api I still cant figure it out. Can u just set it do have an actual output so I can mess with it.

Comment: 1. Go to your working directory (the directory where you already installed express)
2. Execute the command  `npm install --save puppeteer` (this will take a while because it will download a chrome binary)
3. Create a new file called `example.js` in your working directory
4. Copy & Paste the code from https://pastebin.com/RyVfsaM9 into `example.js`
5. Execute the command `node example.js`
6. Open your webbrowser and navigate to http://localhost:3000/teslamotors/followers